# Accepting any type of STL container and using its value type

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, gcc

I have a function that operates on an STL container of any type and needs to the pass the container's element type to another template function. Actually, when I say any container type I don't really mean it. Strictly only vectors and arrays. I have something like this:

```
template <typename T> int ProcessData(T data)
{
  return DoInternalProcessing<T::value_type>(data.data(), data.size());
}
```

MSVC11 accepts this code but gcc does not. What's wrong with it? For gcc I thought about also having the value type be a parameter but then that would require the caller to specify T (the container type) which would be very unwieldy with std::array and this function's primary purpose is to provide a very simple interface that abstracts away from the underlying data.

Comment: What error does gcc give?

Comment: `return DoInternalProcessing<typename T::value_type>(data.data(), data.size());`?

Comment: error: unexpected type name 'value_type': expected expression

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: That works perfectly for both compilers! I suspect this is a case where MSVC is not following the standard as strictly as it should...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `T::value_type` is a dependent type, you need `typename T::value_type`.

This won't work with an array though -- an array won't provide a typedef of `value_type` like a `vector` does.

The usual way to handle this would be to accept a pair of iterators (or pointers, if the underlying "collection" is an array). In this case, you can use `std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type` to get the value type to which the iterator refers. This will work with raw pointers, so (for example) `std::iterator_traits<int *>::value_type` will yield `int`.

If you really have to use a container (and support arrays), you could use `std::begin(data)` to get an iterator to the beginning of the data, then use `std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type` on that to get the value_type.

Comment: By array I mean std::array which does provide value_type so using 'typename T::value_type' will work here for all cases.